# Where's this place and what's this game called?

Tags: game-identification

She is at which place? Near what area? And what is this game called?
She is near some atmosphere where there is a moon or sun thats purplish.
She had some wings on the back of her. Maybe she is holding something?

[image: Mythical woman with wings]

Original Source URL: https://s20.postimg.org/4bjs8hljx/Mythical_Desert_Rappelz.png (now defunct)

Comment: The information you're after seems to be in the image's file name.

Comment: @JamesOfDaPeach: You can copy the image URL into Google, and there should be an option at the top for showing results.

Answer (score 8):

As it says in the filename, this is from [Rappelz](http://rappelz.gpotato.com/).  Rappelz is a free to play MMO, so you can give it a shot and see if you like it.

I'd say the character is in the Mythical Desert, but it looks more like that's a soundtrack than a location in-game.  There's not nearly enough detail there to determine where they are.